# gh-pages not loading bundle.js from index.html

Tags: reactjs, webpack, github-pages, html-webpack-plugin

I have set up a React project with `webpack`.I want to upload this project on my user site on Github.
I created the user site repository with 2 branches- `master` and `gh-pages`.
The project structure is as follows:

```
 dist
    index.html
    bundle.js
 index.html
```

The `Package.json` file has the following commands for build and deployment.

```
 "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --content-base ./dist",
 "test": "npm run lint && npm run security-check && npm run bundle",
 "predeploy": "npm run build",
 "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
```

In dev mode, the project is working fine.The `HtmlWebPackPlugin` is inserting the bundle js script tag in the `dist/index.html`.
For deploying to gh-pages, when I run the deploy command, the code is updated correctly in the branch gh-pages. I can see the latest `dist` folder files in there.

But the user site is giving me `404: not found error` for `bundle.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research on gh-pages,I found the solution.
For user pages,Github only allows publishing from `master` branch.So the `index.html` and `bundle.js` should be present in the master branch,and they will be served as static resources.

This is a little confusing as 
in other apps,you can choose to build from master or gh-pages branch,or from the /docs directory.

So I created a `development` branch,where my source stays.
And I modified the deploy command to upload code from the `development` branch to `master`.

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist -b master"
```